# I can't get data from specific root in FireBase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an android app and I have problem to retrieve data from a specific node in firebase.

[image: This is my database structure]

How can I retrieve **only the data which is located in "Posts"** to my listview?

I'm using addChildEventListener like that:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        dataArrayList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            TrempData trempData2 = ds.getValue(TrempData.class);
            dataArrayList.add(0, trempData2);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you initialize `mDatabase`? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: thank you for editing my question.. i wrote what you ask for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get just the posts, attach your listener to the `Posts` child node:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

I changed this to a `ValueEventListener` because you seem to expect to get all data in one go.

In [`onDataChange` of the listener, you can then loop over the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    dataArrayList.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        TrempData trempData2 = ds.getValue(TrempData.class);
        dataArrayList.add(0, trempData2);
    }
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works great but i have new problem.. I cant delete value from "Posts".  When i used the addChildEventListener i had a code for delete specific value inside onChildRemoved. How can i make it happen with the addValueEventListener?

Comment: Your `onDataChange` will trigger again, and you will get the full list of data for the location. If you don't want that, you should use `addValueEventListener`, which triggers for the individual child that was affected in the update.

Comment: But now when i click on the delete button it dosent delete the value from firebase.. its ok to edit the main qustion with the new problem(with code)?

Comment: Its all good!!! I modified my delete button OnClickListener. Thank you very much my friend!!